# Grunt wiredep not injecting font-awesome

Tags: javascript, bower, font-awesome, grunt-wiredep

I'm currently working on a project that had already been started using `yeoman`.

For some reason, when I run `grunt-wiredep` all dependencies are correclty injected in my `index.html` except for `font-awesome`.

Here's my `bower.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "watermelon",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.3",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-google-maps-native": "~2.0.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "bootstrap-switch": "~3.3.2",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "~4.15.35",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.4.0",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "ng-tags-input": "3.0.0",
    "requirejs": "latest",
    "requirejs-domready": "latest",
    "stacktrace-js": "~0.6.4",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3"
  },
  "appPath": "."
}
```

And a link to `Gruntfile.js`: http://pastebin.com/xxZwAYRW

When I run `grunt-wiredep` only these css dependencies get injected:

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This problem broke with the [latest(4.4.0) commit to FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/commit/7cde41ea934f43e66dc123ea6411d8535b50a4f7).

The fix is pretty straight forward.  You need to set an override (or maybe use less, but I am not going to cover that).

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": ">=4.4.0",
  },  
  "overrides":{
    "font-awesome": {
    "main": [
        "css/font-awesome.css"
    ]
    }
  }
}
```

**OR** (because fontawesome/font-awesome has both names registered)

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "fontawesome": ">=4.4.0",
  },  
  "overrides":{
    "fontawesome": {
    "main": [
        "css/font-awesome.css"
    ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Using this info I rolled back to 4.3 for now.  Seemed easier.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by override bower package
try this code i have edited your **bower.json** look for the change in bottom of this code..
hope it works

```
{
  "name": "watermelon",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.3",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-google-maps-native": "~2.0.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "bootstrap-switch": "~3.3.2",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "~4.15.35",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.4.0",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "ng-tags-input": "3.0.0",
    "requirejs": "latest",
    "requirejs-domready": "latest",
    "stacktrace-js": "~0.6.4",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3"
  },  

"overrides":{
    "font-awesome": {
    "main": [
        "css/font-awesome.min.css"
    ]
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. I'd really like to know whether this is a known problem with font-awesome or not.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem here is that he is using `font-awesome` and not `fontawesome`. Check you bower.json  `font-awesom.min.css` is the file name, but the project can be named either.  just run `bower search font-awesome`

Comment: this same fix works for the [issue with bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16663) too

Answer (score 2):

```
bower install components-font-awesome --save
```

should fix it.
It is mentioned on their Github page under Package Managers [here](https://github.com/components/font-awesome)

Comment: Just noticed that this fixes the issue for development using "grunt serve" will work but "grunt build" still misses the fonts on fonts folder, for that you need to add the entry on the Gruntfile.js to copy the fonts, just mimic boostrap fonts and should then work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems bower component "font-awesome" has some issues. You can try using instead "components-font-awesome" in your bower.json, it will solve the issue of not correctly injecting the css file. you can take a look in it's Github repo here: https://github.com/components/font-awesome